# Interactive map

Tags: media, google-maps

I want to make a map like the one on that site: http://www.avito.ma/
Then when I click in a region of the map I'll be redirected to a region of my site .
I'm asking if there is a module that can do this job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A module will only be able to do so much to help you with this because everybody's maps and the precise regions that are highlighted and linked are different!  So you probably would still have to create your own image map to implement the functionality.

I image what they used is the [jQuery Map HiLight](http://drupal.org/project/jq_maphilight) module with an image map to create that page.  The module page itself has some information on how to build your own image map, and what the module adds to that is the highlighting functionality you see when you hover over the map areas.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much,i'll test it and tell you if it's what's i need :D